# Xamarin.ios: string to list skipped code after .Split(",")

Tags: ios, string, listview, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I'm building an iOS app with Xamarin.ios MvvmCross. And I Accomplished to convert the string into a list with `.Split(',')`. Now when I run my code and I want to see the list in my app. The first time I click on an item the viewcell will skip the code after running line `string[] namesArray = FavoriteContent.ingredients.Split(',');` . When I go back to the table view and push the viewcell again. It will run the code and display the list.

The code I display below is in my viewmodel in the .Core project. And I call it in de .IOS project in de views.

Code to make from a string a list and return it:

```
private string _ingredients;

    public string Ingredients
    {
        get
        {
            string[] namesArray = FavoriteContent.ingredients.Split(',');
            List<string> namesList = new List<string>(namesArray.Length);
            namesList.AddRange(namesArray);
            namesList.Reverse();
            _ingredients = string.Join("\n", namesList);
            return _ingredients;
        }
    }
```

This is where I call the list from my views in the .ios project to the .Core project in the viewmodels

ViewController (5th line I call the list):

```
MvxFluentBindingDescriptionSet<DetailFavoriteView, DetailFavoriteViewModel> set = new MvxFluentBindingDescriptionSet<DetailFavoriteView, DetailFavoriteViewModel>(this);
        set.Bind(NameRecipe).To(res => res.FavoriteContent.name);
        set.Bind(DetailImage).For(img => img.Image).To(res => res.FavoriteContent.thumbnail).WithConversion<StringToImageConverter>();
        set.Bind(DescriptionText).To(res => res.FavoriteContent.description);
        set.Bind(IngredientsList).To(res => res.Ingredients);
        set.Bind(ConditionText).To(res => res.Conditions);
        set.Bind(ButtonShopList).To(res => res.PostShopListCommand);
        set.Apply();
```

Comment: Hi , Could you tell us what `IngredientsList` is ? It seems that you are trying to bind listview to a string value.

Comment: IngredientsList just refers to the Label in main.storyboard. And behind Ingredients there's also just a string where I put every word beneath each other with "\n"

Comment: Is `FavoriteContent.ingredients` null when the first time you  click on an item the viewcell?

Comment: Yes FavoriteContent.ingredients is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `FavoriteContent.ingredients` is `null` you'll get an exception in this line `FavoriteContent.ingredients.Split(',');` that will be catched in the binding and therefore your viewcell won't display that content. At the second time your `FavoriteContent.ingredients` is surely not null so it can update the viewcell.

So I think you should just add a null check before doing your logic with `FavoriteContent.ingredients` to avoid the exception:

```
private string _ingredients;

public string Ingredients
{
    get
    {
        if (FavoriteContent?.ingredients == null) // IDK if FavoriteContent is a property or a class, I assumed is a property
            return null; // or return string.empty;

        string[] namesArray = FavoriteContent.ingredients.Split(',');
        List<string> namesList = new List<string>(namesArray.Length);
        namesList.AddRange(namesArray);
        namesList.Reverse();
        _ingredients = string.Join("\n", namesList);
        return _ingredients;
    }
}
```

And then when you load `FavoriteContent.ingredients` you just tell the view to refresh that binding using `RaisePropertyChanged`:

```
// this is the part where you update FavoriteContent.ingredients in your ViewModel so that it is not null
FavoriteContent.ingredients = "my string, my other string, 2, 3";
RaisePropertyChanged(() => Ingredients); // you tell the view Ingredients has changed (make sure you are invoking this in your main thread if not use InvokeOnMainThread(() => RaisePropertyChanged(() => Ingredients));)
```

HIH